# Robots.txt - What is the proper format for a Crawl Delay for multiple user agents?

Tags: format, web-crawler, robots.txt, agents

Below is a sample **robots.txt** file to Allow **multiple user agents** with **multiple crawl delays** for each user agent. The Crawl-delay values are for illustration purposes and will be different in a real robots.txt file.

I have searched all over the web for proper answers but could not find one. There are too many mixed suggestions and I do not know which is the correct / proper method.

**Questions:**

(1) Can each user agent have it's own crawl-delay? (I assume yes)

(2) Where do you put the crawl-delay line for each user agent, before or after the Allow / Dissallow line?

(3) Does there have to be a blank like between each user agent group.

References:

http://www.seopt.com/2013/01/robots-text-file/

http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1113851#1113858

Essentially, I am looking to find out how the final robots.txt file should look using the values in the sample below.

Thanks in advance.

```
# Allow only major search spiders    
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 11

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 12

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 13

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 14

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 15

User-agent: MSNBot
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 16

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 17

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 18

User-agent: Yahoo! Slurp
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 19

# Block all other spiders
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# Block Directories for all spiders
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ads/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /scripts/
```

(4) If I want to set all of the user agents to have crawl delay of 10 seconds, would the following be correct?

```
# Allow only major search spiders
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:

User-agent: Adsbot-Google
Disallow:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow:

User-agent: MSNBot
Disallow:

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow:

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow:

User-agent: Yahoo! Slurp
Disallow:

# Block all other spiders
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# Block Directories for all spiders
User-agent: *
Disallow: /ads/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /scripts/
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> (1) Can each user agent have it's own crawl-delay?

Yes. Each *record*, started by one or more `User-agent` lines, can have a `Crawl-delay` line. Note that `Crawl-delay` is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). But it’s no problem to include them for those parsers that understand it, as the spec [defines](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format):

> Unrecognised headers are ignored.

So older robots.txt parsers will simply ignore your `Crawl-delay` lines.

---

> (2) Where do you put the crawl-delay line for each user agent, before or after the Allow / Dissallow line?

Doesn’t matter.

---

> (3) Does there have to be a blank like between each user agent group.

Yes. *Records* have to be separated by one or more new lines. See the [original spec](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format):

> The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more blank lines (terminated by CR,CR/NL, or NL).

---

> (4) If I want to set all of the user agents to have crawl delay of 10 seconds, would the following be correct?

No. Bots look for records that match their user-agent. Only if they don’t find a record, they will use the `User-agent: *` record. So in your example all the listed bots (like `Googlebot`, `MSNBot`, `Yahoo! Slurp` etc.) will have *no* `Crawl-delay`.

---

Also note that you can’t have [several records with `User-agent: *`](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html#format):

> If the value is '*', the record describes the default access policy for any robot that has not matched any of the other records. **It is not allowed to have multiple such records in the "/robots.txt" file.**

So parsers might look (if no other record matched) for the first record with `User-agent: *` and ignore the following ones. For your first example that would mean that URLs beginning with `/ads/`, `/cgi-bin/` and `/scripts/` are *not* blocked.

And even if you have only *one* record with `User-agent: *`, those `Disallow` lines are only for bots that have no other record match! As your comment `# Block Directories for all spiders` suggest, you want these URL paths to be blocked for *all* spiders, so you’d have to repeat the `Disallow` lines for *every* record.